# Write structured commands in multiple lines with tab key activated

Tags: bash

I'd like to write structured command in multiple lines as

```
$ for i in *;
→ do
→    file $i;
→ done
bmdt.md: ASCII text
breakfast.md: ASCII text
brmdh.md: ASCII text
test.sh: Bourne-Again shell script text executable, ASCII text
```

but find the tab not working,

How could I activate the tab key in the bash console?

Comment: press Control-V Tab instead; Tab is bound to file/command completion by default.

Comment: Why care to insert TABs in interactive commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering an incomplete command, the `bash` shell will show a continuation prompt (the secondary prompt, `$PS2`) and allow you to complete the entered command.  The command line editing facilities of the shell at that point is the same as at the original prompt (the primary prompt, `$PS1`), which means that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key would do command and filename completion as usual.

To insert a tab character, use <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or use spaces for indentation.  Tab characters (or any other literal character) can always be inserted if prefixed by <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.

---

Alternatively, if in Emacs command line editing mode (which I believe is the default in `bash`), use <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> to bring up an editor to enter your command into.  The editor used will be the one specified by the `EDITOR` shell/environment variable, or `emacs` if this variable is unset.

In Vi command line editing mode, press <kbd>Escape</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> to do the same thing.

The command will be executed after saving and exiting the editor.

Comment: Could I ask What's vi command line, I am aware the Vim is a editor which should be opened in advance, go inside, and edit, rather than directly type into command and run.

Comment: @avirate Vim is a variant of the original Vi editor. "Vi command line editing mode" is a mode that you enable with `set -o vi` and that gives you the ability to use Vi/Vim editing commands on the command line, like (`Esc`) `dw` to delete to the end of the current word etc.  Use `set -o emacs` to get back to Emacs command line editing mode.

Comment: amazing,I immediately search and explore it.

Comment: @avirate Note that the editor doesn't need to be opened in advance. If you press `Ctrl+X` `Ctrl+E`, the shell will open it for you.